# Asp.Net: WebService generate file and allow user to download it

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, download

I have WebService, which generate xls-file:

```
[WebMethod]
    public void DownloadReport5()
    {
        string returnedValue;
        Dictionary<string, object> parametersForRep5 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        uint dateOffset = Convert.ToUInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateOffset"]);
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        string urlToFileFormat = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlToFileFormat"];
        string filenameFormat = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilenameFormat"];
        string pathToXsltDoc = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[GenericReportCreator.PathToXsltDoc];

        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        CitiesConfigSection citiesConfigSection = (CitiesConfigSection)config.GetSection("RequiredCities");

        string[] requiredCities = citiesConfigSection.CitiesName.ToArray();

        parametersForRep5.Add("DateOffset", dateOffset);
        parametersForRep5.Add("ConnectionString", connectionString);
        parametersForRep5.Add("UrlToFileFormat", urlToFileFormat);
        parametersForRep5.Add("FilenameFormat", filenameFormat);
        parametersForRep5.Add("RequiredCities", requiredCities);
        parametersForRep5.Add(GenericReportCreator.PathToXsltDoc, Server.MapPath(pathToXsltDoc));

        returnedValue = this.ReportCreator.CreateReportDoc(TypeOfReport.Rep5, parametersForRep5);

        NetworkProcessor np = new NetworkProcessor();
        np.SendFileToClient(Context.Response, returnedValue);            
    }
```

CreateReportDoc method generate xls-file of required report.
I want to call this method by AJAX and allow user download generated file, for it I use next code:

```
<script>
    function DownloadDevicesInfo() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/TechnologyHelpdeskService.asmx/DownloadReport5",
            contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel;",
            success: function (response) { OnDownloadDevicesInfoSuccess(response); },
            error: function (response) { OnDownloadDevicesInfoError(response); }
        })
    }

    function OnDownloadDevicesInfoSuccess(response) {
        alert("success");
    }


    function OnDownloadDevicesInfoError(response) {
        alert("MyError:" + response.status + " " + response.statusText);
    }
</script>
```

But I donn't any request to download file and I cann't understand why. Can anybody tell me, whats wrong, may be I should process response on success function?